# Align middle 2 elements in Boostrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is what I want to do with BS3:

[My beautiful schema :)](http://i.imgur.com/yXPgFtT.png)

And this is my start code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large pull-left"></i>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque molestias nihil quia!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle URL - http://jsfiddle.net/AJAhR/54/

I tried with line-height but it must be responsive so it doesn't work.

Someone can explain me how to do that with CSS/Boostrap3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something with position absolute

```
 .well.well-sm p { margin-left: 60px; /* with of the icons + icon's padding right */ }
 .well.well-sm { position: relative; }
 .well.well-sm i { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; margin-top: -50px; /* 50% of the icon's height */ }
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/AJAhR/55/

Comment: Thanks! I just add margin-bottom: 0 to the p element and it's perfect.